nestjs typeOrm errors e-commerce
[Nest] 98141  - 05/05/2024, 3:43:43 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
at OrderController.makeOrder (/Users/macbook/Documents/Projects/org gast/gast/src/basket/basket.controller.ts:48:51)
at /Users/macbook/Documents/Projects/org gast/gast/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:38:29
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at /Users/macbook/Documents/Projects/org gast/gast/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
at /Users/macbook/Documents/Projects/org gast/gast/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
wtf? how to solve this problem?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
